# Will there still be gehinom after Mashiach?

Tags: death, messiah, heaven

Apart for those who are destined to no share in the world to come, will tzadikim or even average people who go to olam habah after Mashaich comes have to go to gehinom to cleanse their sins? Or will they go straight to Gan Eden?

Comment: I think a good question would be if there will be anyone doing anything wrong after Moshiach comes. If everyone's doing _exactly_ what they're supposed to, there won't be any need for Gehinnom. But whether that makes it not exist anymore is beyond me.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit why you think Gehinnom will no longer exist after Moshiach comes.